# Using Slice() in function with Rvest

Tags: r

I am trying to create a function that scrapes the `player name` from each `html` source I pass. The problem is that the scrape is creating two erroneous rows at the beginning, so I would like to `slice` the data frame to exclude the first two rows. However, the number of rows is variable, so I can't hard code the last row.

```
####  Libraries -------------------
library(rvest)
library(XML)
library(dplyr)

# Set source as example
site <- "http://www.pgatour.com/stats/stat.138.html"

get_player_name <- function(site){
  player <- html(paste(site)) %>%
    html_nodes(".player-name") %>%
    html_text(trim=TRUE) %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    slice(3:max(nrow(.)))            # Drop the first two rows
    #slice(3:73)                     # This works for one site but not all = 73
  names(player)[1] <- "PLAYER NAME"  # Rename the column
  player$ID <- seq.int(nrow(player)) # Create index variable
  return(player)
}
```

When I run:

```
a <- get_player_name(site)
```

The I get the following error:

```
Error: result would be too long a vector
In addition: Warning message:
In slice_impl(.data, dots) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

Comment: _"(B) You shall not use or permit or facilitate others to use PGATOUR.com by automated electronic processes, robots, spiders, scrapers, webcrawlers, or other computer programs that monitor, copy or download data or other content found on or accessed through PGATOUR.com, including without limitation real time scoring, video, audio, statistics, polling, or data content, whether current or archival._" http://www.pgatour.com/company/tos.html (just cuz you can doesn't mean you should)

Comment: Thanks for this info--immediately ceasing any scraping. Should've looked before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `-` to tell `slice()` the rows you *don't* want:

```
slice(-c(1,2))
```